# tomcat on 8080 under ELB using ACM for SSL

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, ssl, amazon-elb

Currently, I am trying to configure the https for one of my tomcat which is under ELB and for SSL certificate I have used aws certificate manager and pointed to the ELB.

My Elb listeners ports are

ELB port 80 ---> Instance port --> 8080
ELB port 443 --> Instance port --> 8080 with ACM certificate.

Is any configuration that needs to be in tomcat level or any method to run my site with https using ACM?

Comment: Are you trying to get HTTP to HTTPS redirects to work or something? If so you need to check the `x-forwarded-for` HTTP header to determine if the client is connecting to the load balancer over HTTP or HTTPS. Otherwise, add more details about what issue you are experiencing, because your setup as you described it should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your can put NGNIX in each tomcat instance , Nginx is super reliable and has the smallest footprint I ever seen in a serious web server.

**Then in  NGNIX Config**

NGINX will rewrite all requests to the ELB calling the HTTPS port utilizing status 301.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name myhost.com;
  # add ssl settings
  return 301 https://myhost.com$request_uri;
}
```

**Tomcat Config:**

Now you need to touch the server.xml configuration of Tomcat (located @ $TOMCAT/conf/server.xml) .

```
<Connector scheme="https" secure="true" proxyPort="443"
  port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
  connectionTimeout="25000"
  URIEncoding="UTF-8"
  redirectPort="8443" />
```

**Amazon Elastic Load Balancer:**

You have to configure in the AWS ELB the following listeners.

```
 HTTP 80 -> HTTP 80 (nginx)
 HTTPS 443 -> HTTP 8080 (tomcat)
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: thanks for the info, I have done some modifications to nginx now I am able to run on https but  it is showing unsecured.

Comment: you might be serving mixed contents , please refer this guide https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/fixing-mixed-content

And if I solved your question , please mark the answer as solved so community can benefit from it